# how to convert space separated list into 'TextFileReader object' generated by chunksize

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a **space-separated list**

```
ad= [12  6  8 ...  3  3  9]
```

it is generated by this piece of code:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', dtype={'acoustic_data': np.int16, 'time_to_failure': np.float32})
          
failure_idxs = [500, 1000, 104677356, 138772453, 187641820, 218652630,245829585, 307838917, 338276287, 375377848, 419368880, 461811623,
                            495800225, 528777115, 585568144, 621985673]
        
for idx in failure_idxs:
    ad = train_df['acoustic_data'].values[idx - 150000: idx + 30000]
    print("ad=",ad)
# =============================================================================
#            see below function is not running on 'list' ad 
# =============================================================================
    
    #ch = gen_features(ad)  
    break
```

I want to convert above **space-separated list** into 'TextFileReader object' format generated by chunksize:

```
acoustic_data= 0       12
1        6
2        8
3        5
4        8
        ..
1544     4
1545     0
1546     3
1547     3
1548     9
```

In the above 'TextFileReader object' has **first column is index number** separating with **tab** the **actual(current) value** and **the next value index is** separated with **the end line**.
how I can do convert programmatically in python the **space-separated list** into 'TextFileReader object' given above?

The above 'TextFileReader object' is generated by this piece of code

```
train1 = pd.read_csv('train.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=150000, dtype={'acoustic_data': np.int16, 'time_to_failure': np.float64})
for df in train1:
    print("acoustic_data=",df['acoustic_data'])
    ch = gen_features(df['acoustic_data'])
    break
```

You can download the sample code from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JlS1XISPBb_0EScHaxzHc4rR80ZXmiZM/view?usp=sharing) and run using python ide like spyder pychar etc.

Comment: That's a string, a (potentially incomplete) string representation of a numpy array.

Comment: @hpaulj do you mean 'space-separated list' is a string representation of a NumPy array.How to convert 'space-separated list' into 'TextFileReader object' format generated by chunksize??